# Can sheet laminate be applied securely to a wall that is currently painted chipboard?

Tags: walls, laminate

I own a dog daycare and boarding facility.  Our walls are currently painted chipboard.  This is a problem, as the texture makes it very difficult to keep clean.  We would like to install sheet laminate in the satin touch texture over the painted chipboard.  The smooth, nonporous texture will make cleaning it much easier.  Is that possible?  If so, how?  What products would we need?

Comment: Is the paint very well bonded to the chip board?  Any adhesive you use will be between the paint and laminate.  If you do not trust the paint, use 1/4 inch plywood first.  Most contact or construction adhesives should work for holding the laminate to the wall.

Comment: You might be annoyed by holding laminate up while ordinary glue sets. You need some additional material to hold the laminate in place as you wait on the glue. @crip's contact cement will eliminate that, but the stress of getting everything aligned just right within a tight time window now becomes the problem. Choose your poison.